# No funciona mi botón de editar en VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente userform:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando toco un elemento de la lista los campos se cambian, pero al momento de darle editar solamente se modifica la fecha inicial:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi botón de editar:

```vb
Private Sub btn_editar_Click()
 
Dim fila As Object
Dim linea As Variant
 
 
codigo = LISTA.List(LISTA.ListIndex, 0)
 
Set fila = Sheets("BD_MC").Range("A:A").Find(codigo, lookat:=xlWhole)
linea = fila.row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD_MC").Range("B" & linea).Value = Me.Fecha_MC.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD_MC").Range("C" & linea).Value = Me.Categoria.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD_MC").Range("D" & linea).Value = Me.Patente.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD_MC").Range("E" & linea).Value = Me.MR.Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD_MC").Range("F" & linea).Value = Me.Fecha_MC_finalizacion.Value

 
End Sub
```

Si cambio el orden funciona otro campo en vez de fecha, pero solo uno.

Comment: Ejecutalo con F8 paso a paso para ver por qué falla.